# Adding numbers to lists in Python but will add 1 and 0 instead of 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Still in my quest for the Josephus problem, I ran across a small problem in the following code

(example code showing the problem without all the Josephus crap, exact same issue with both)

```
listy = []
var = 0

while var < 15:
     var += 1
     listy += str(var)
     print("var: ", str(var))
     print(listy)
     print("")

 print("")
 print(listy)
```

Instead of adding, for example, 10 to the list, it will add 1 and 0. So instead of listy looking like:

```
 ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11']
```

etc as it should, it looks like:

```
 ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '1', '0', '1', '1']
```

etc. So the full output of the above gave this:[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/umwUX.png)

Any help?

Comment: Yes, don't use `+=` to add the string objects to your list, use `.append`.

Comment: ah thanks, i'm used to +=

Comment: `listy += [str(var)]`

Comment: @MauriceMeyer no, why would you do that? Just use `.append`

Answer (score 2):

Changing

```
listy += str(var)
```

to

```
listy.append(str(var))
```

fixes the problem